# VBA: XMLHTTP request fails until I toggle POST/GET

Tags: excel, vba, rest, xmlhttprequest

Okay, I need the internet's collective wisdom on this one.

I'm calling an API from Excel (code abbreviated, most of this code I got online. Need to use late binding, but not sure if MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0 is the best to use - Excel 365):

```
Dim body as String
Dim request as Object
Dim isAsync as Boolean

Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
isAsync = False
body = "...just some query params"

With request
    .Open "POST", authUrl, isAsync
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    .send body
    'spin wheels whilst waiting for response
    While request.ReadyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    Debug.print(.responseText)
End With
```

The issue I'm having is that the first time this code runs, it fails on the `.send body` line with the following error:
[image]

However, if I change `"POST"` to `"GET"` it will fail again, albeit because the server doesn't accept that method apparently. But then if I change it back to `POST` and run it again, it runs fine!

Then, if I save the file, close Excel, open the file again and try to run, again it's the same error as above!

So why am I having to "shake" it like this, toggling the method back and forth? It doesn't make any sense to me why that works. Obviously, I can't tell my end users to mess with the code like this, so I'd like to know what's happening. What can I test and try?

**Update (May 5):**

If I put a breakpoint at `.send body` then try to step over that (it errors), and debug, I see that `request.status` has a value of 12019, which is apparently some kind of bogus IE error code (?). I am running this on a machine that has IE 11, Edge, and Chrome installed. Would changing the User Agent string do anything? I tried the Chrome string as given on MDN, as well as just "MyApp" but it didn't change anything.

At this point, I'm wondering if I have to just do `On Error Resume Next`, try it as-is, then send the request again with `GET` and then again with `POST` and see if that works, although that's a hateful, hacky workaround.

Comment: Do you have the link to the API documentation to share?

Comment: what is the auth url ?

can you ping the url before posting ?

Comment: The authUrl is a company-internal endpoint that I get a token from. If I do a test request using Postman, both GET and POST return a token, but not in VBA. How would I "ping" the URL from VBA, and what would that accomplish? I am confident it's not an issue with the server being down.

Comment: Have you used something like fiddler to check the response when you perform the post?

Comment: So if I copy my whole `With request` block (so there's now 2 in the function), and make the first one GET, the GET returns an error from the API (but at least the request went through), and then the POST one after returns the expected (good) result. I hate having an extra "only to shake it hard enough to work" block like that. Is there something about VBA using maybe IE to do a POST before anything else that it doesn't like, or what?